# Mocking Popen to return different results depending on call_args

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytest

I am calling a function `def sftp(cmdstr, server):` which calls Popen to call the systems sftp client.

The issue I have is I have a `main` function which calls `sftp` twice with different args. The first time with an `ls` and the second time it will be to `get` files. I have mocked call but I cant work out how to branch the return value.

If the first call i want it link below to return a string.
If the second call I want it to create files using tmpdir.mkdir() so the files "appear" as if they have been downloaded. The files need to be physically present due to the manipulation that happens later in the code.

```
p_open = mocker.patch('mymodule.Popen', autospec=True)
mock_rv = mocker.Mock()
mock_rv.returncode = None
stdout_sftp = 'sftp> cd /upload\nsftp> ' \
    'ls\n{0}               {1}               \n{2}' \
    '               \nsftp> bye\n'.format(
        sftp_idf_file_list[0],
        sftp_idf_file_list[1],
        sftp_idf_file_list[2]
    )
mock_rv.communicate.return_value = [stdout_sftp, 'output_err']
p_open.return_value = mock_rv
```

Anyone know how to make:
   `mock_rv.communicate.return_value = [stdout_sftp, 'output_err']`
refer to a function that only gets called when the mock is called not before during setup?

One more caveat, code must be compatible with both python2.7 and 3.6.

Regards,

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use a lambda & monkeypatch.

First we mock the call to Popen so we have all the properties, then we set the returncode so that we dont error in the main code.

Finally we set the lambda in the communicate which is where we actually make the sftp call. If my call has 'ls' in it i want a dir listing so i return a string of what the stdout would look like from the sftp call.
On the other hand in this case if there is no 'ls' I want to run a get command, so instead of 'getting' I just execute a method that creates the files in the destination directory.

```
stdout_sftp = 'sftp> cd /upload\nsftp> ' \
    'ls\n{0}               {1}               \n{2}' \
    '               \nsftp> bye\n'.format(
        sftp_idf_file_list[0],
        sftp_idf_file_list[1],
        sftp_idf_file_list[2]
    )

def create_tmp_files(tdir, flist):
    """ Used to create temp files to simulate sftp"""
    for file_ in flist:
        current_file = tdir.join(file_)
        current_file.write('')
    return "stdout", "stderror"


monkeypatch.setattr('mymodule.Popen', mocker.Mock())
monkeypatch.setattr('mymodule.Popen.return_value.returncode',
                    None)
monkeypatch.setattr('mymodule.Popen.return_value.communicate',
                    lambda x: (stdout_sftp, "stderror")
                    if '\nls\n' in x
                    else create_tmp_files(
                        dst_dir,
                        file_list))
```